# How to check state of the pollable connection in WSO2 ESB 3.0.1

Tags: datasource, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a datasource in ESB:

```
Driver              oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 
URL                 jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = ... ) 
Pool Type           BasicDataSource
Repository Type     JNDI 
Max Active          20 
Max Idle            1 
Max Wait            30000 
Min Idle            0 
Initial Size        0 
Max Open Statements 50 
Transaction Isolation   TRANSACTION_UNKNOWN
Auto Commit         false
Pool Statements     true
Test On Borrow      true
Test While Idle     true
Validation Query    select 1 from dual
```

On database level I have a limit for my user 100 connections.

In ESB Data source 20.

But sometimes i'm reaching the database limit: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

How I can check how many connections in the pool?

I tried JMX but did not found proper mbean.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a bug in JNDI connections.

when i use JNDI based datasource, and have max active = 20,

server allows to borrow 20 connections to every thread!

and if I use inmemory datasource, then 20 is a limit to all threads.

so, the problem is solved, but the bug still there.